# Wrong size when exporting png from Sketch

Tags: export, png, sketch-3

I've an image that I set to 37x37 in Sketch and then export it in @1x, @2x and @3x sizes using the Export option as in the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

When examining the images after export the are not symmetrical - one side is off. Is this a Sketch bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am also flagging this question as off-topic. It has nothing to do with programing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I got the export to work, i.e. giving me the correct sizes, if I use the export button on the top right instead of the export facility on the lower right.

Comment: This worked for me, I suppose this is a bug with 44.